# drupal ubercart stock management

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I hope someone can assist me with Ubercart.

When purchasing on the site, you can add as many products as you want to the cart regardless of whether there is only a certain number of items in stock.

Is there a way where when a user tries to purchase 10 items and there are only 5 items, the user then gets limited to a quantity of 5 only? 
Here is an example of what I mean:

[How much stock there is on the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d2Y5.png)

[How much stock can be added to to shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cllm.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you need is [Ubercart Out of Stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_out_of_stock) module

Comment: Thank you Augusto, I actually had the module installed and turns out that it was just a configuration setting to make the stock management option active in the module. Will make sure to check if my configuration settings are correct next time before asking.